# Mail.app like source list footer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

Is there a built in way to create a Mail like footer for a source list in a Mac app?

[image: Mail.app source list footer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing explicit that I can think of.

You'll have to either subclass `NSView` to draw a footer (via [`drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/drawRect%3a)) or have a subview that hangs onto the bottom edge of the parent view.  Then you can add in buttons with images or pop-down menus, like [`NSPopupButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/).